# Retrieve the data sent as JSON from JavaScript, inside a servlet

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I have a query on retrieving data sent as JSON from a JavaScript, inside a Java servlet. 
Following is what I am doing...

This is the part of the code inside JavaScript making a request to a servlet

```
type : "POST",
url: 'getInitialData',
datatype: 'json',
data : ({items :[{ name: "John", time: "2pm" },{name: "Sam", time: "1pm" }]}),
success: function(data) {
    try{
          ////Code to be handeled where response is recieved
       }catch(e){
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

On making this request I try to retrieve the parameters sent from JavaScript in a Servlet, but while doing so I was firstly confused on how to retrieve the dat from the request

I used the following in my servlet:

**NOTE :** the content Type in my Servlet is set to : **apllication/json**

```
 response.setContentType("application/json");

 request.getParameterMap();
```

the above showed me the data as below, but I was not able figure out how to work and get the actual data

```
{items[1][name]=[Ljava.lang.String;@1930089, items[0][time]=[Ljava.lang.String;@860ba, items[1][time]=[Ljava.lang.String;@664ca, items[0][name]=[Ljava.lang.String;@1c334de}
```

while the following code gave me Exception of null which was expected.

```
request.getParametervalues("items");
```

Among the others i tried where request.getParameter(); request.getParameterNames(); but in vain...

Am I in a wrong direction? Please guide me!
Please let me know how to retieve these value.

Thank You for reading this long post...

Sangeet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The request parameter map is a `Map<String, String[]>` where the map key is the parameter name and map value are the parameter values --HTTP allows more than one value on the same name.

Given the printout of your map, the following should work:

```
String item0Name = request.getParameter("items[0][name]");
String item0Time = request.getParameter("items[0][time]");
String item1Name = request.getParameter("items[1][name]");
String item1Time = request.getParameter("items[1][time]");
```

If you want a bit more dynamics, use the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    String itemName = request.getParameter("items[" + i + "][name]");
    String itemTime = request.getParameter("items[" + i + "][time]");

    if (itemName == null) {
        break;
    }

    // Collect name and time in some bean and add to list yourself.
}
```

Note that setting the **response** content type is irrelevant when it comes to gathering the **request** parameters.

Comment: Thanks A lot BalusC that worked like magic.... And sorry for the guidance regarding response content type...that was really un-necessary in the post.... Thanks a lot again...